# Spatial Data conversion and persistency issue for shapefile in OSGB36

Tags: c#, gps, gis, wgs84

I am looking for a tool that meets the following requirements

1) Ability to import shapefile in osgb36 format to database (sql server 2005/2008) programmatically.
2) Ability to convert OSGB36 to WGS84 programmatically.
3) Compitable with .NET framework. (e.g. in C#)

I tried a few, but none of them work.

I want the tool to import osgb36 shapefile to database (may convert it to wgs84 before storing in database) in a .NET environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to help you out. I've got the tools to read shapefiles in WGS84 format and insert into SQL2008. But I don't have the conversion formula from OSGB36 -> WGS84, so am stuck on that point.

If you find a .NET conversion, then let me know and I'll integrate it into the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to comment on jjrdk's answer but I can't find a way to. Just wanted to say, I have used the [Grid InQuest DLL](http://www.qgsl.com/?product=gridinquest) to do the coordinate conversions. It's managed code but you can call it from .NET, and it is the 'official' Ordnance Survey high-accuracy way of doing it (accurate to a few cms.)

I also have numerous bits and pieces of other code which is accurate to about 7m, if that's all you want I can post the source/links.

I've been using Shp2SQL to import shapes to geometry and geography data types, unfortunately it has no source code. If anyone knows anything better than that I'd love to hear about it. I do have libraries to read SHP files - I can post the links if you want them.